# 'confluent start' : Cannot start Kafka, Zookeeper is not running

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, confluent-platform

I am receiving following error while starting confluent platform:

```
$ ./confluent start
Starting zookeeper
|Zookeeper failed to start
zookeeper is [DOWN]
Cannot start Kafka, Zookeeper is not running. Check your deployment
```

I have my Zookeeper running on port 2181  and Kafka on port 9092.

Comment: Please post the output of `confluent log zookeeper`

Comment: Confluent runs it's own zoo keeper instance [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45629413/7882470)

Answer (score 14):

Just run the below command to stop the zookeeper server

> path-to-confluent> ./bin/zookeeper-server-stop

And start confluent using the command:

> path-to-confluent> ./bin/confluent start